# Ran minifyXmlString function on XML in IntelliJ; it worked, but within larger codebase, it returned an empty string, cause unclear

Tags: java, java-8, utf-8

I ran this code on my local IntelliJ Idea:

```
public static String minify(String xml) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(xml));
    return (String)reader.lines().map(String::trim).collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

I ran this code with this XML:

```
<get_DL_Response_v4 xmlns="http://tempuri.org/REC_3YRMVR_WS/REC_3YRMVR_WS">
    <return_cd>string</return_cd>
    <return_msg>string</return_msg>
    <cust_input>
        <dln>string</dln>
        <vendor_num>string</vendor_num>
        <naic_id>string</naic_id>
        <cust_text>string</cust_text>
    </cust_input>    
</get_DL_Response_v4>
```

Here is how it looks:
[image]

This code is integrated into a larger codebase. I extracted the XML from the debugger and independently executed the minify function on it. When run in isolation, it generates the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><get_DL_Response_v4 xmlns="http://tempuri.org/REC_3YRMVR_WS/REC_3YRMVR_WS"><return_cd>string</return_cd><return_msg>string</return_msg><cust_input><dln>string</dln><vendor_num>string</vendor_num><naic_id>string</naic_id><cust_text>string</cust_text></cust_input></get_DL_Response_v4>
```

My debugging of the minified code within a larger codebase resulted in an empty string for output. I'm uncertain if the presence of non-UTF-8 characters causes this. After inputting the XML into an online editor to check for non-printable characters, the only things visible were carriage returns and line feeds (CR LF). I'm puzzled as to why the identical code is yielding different results.